# How do I wrap Python 3's io.BytesIO() with surrogateescape decoding?

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

I've found Python3's `open("filename", "r", encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape")` to be useful. How do I wrap an `io.BytesIO()` (or any not-a-real-file source of bytes) to create a text-mode file-like object with the same decoding behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [TextIOWrapper](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) does.